# Making JMenuItem show one JPanel and hide another

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jmenuitem

I'd like to be able to switch between two possible JPanels in my frame by selecting a certain JMenuItem. What I tried so far:

Action listener in my JMenuBar class:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(fullList))
            gui.switchToFullList();
        else if (e.getSource().equals(history))
            gui.switchToHistory();
}
```

In GUI class:

```
void switchToFullList() {
    remove(history);
    add(fullList);
}

void switchToHistory() {
    remove(fullList);
    add(history);
}
```

where `history` and `fullList` are JPanels.

This doesn't seem to modify my frame in any way.

Comment: I'd recommend using [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show one Panel and hide another, they both should ba childreen of your Frame, then you can acces those Panels by: frame.JpanelName.

Example of removing history and adding fullList:

```
frame.remove(frame.history);
frame.getContentPane().add(frame.fullList);
frame.validate();
frame.repaint();
```

Comment: What is the difference between `frame.add(...)` and `frame.getContentPane().add(...)`?